# Pandas get the average last hour speed from accumulated network data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which record the **accumulated** network traffic (bytes) from several programs at certain (but not constant) interval. It is like the "all time download / upload" data in some programs. The DataFrame is constantly renewing, some columns are deleted and some are added. The index is pandas.DatetimeIndex.
Looks like this:

```
                            Program_A       Program_B       Program_C
2020-10-21 19:30:01.352301  100             200             NaN
2020-10-21 19:45:01.245997  200             250             NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-10-22 17:30:01.123456  10000           700             NaN
2020-10-22 17:45:01.158689  30000           700             NaN
2020-10-22 18:00:01.191560  50000           700             NaN
2020-10-22 18:15:01.208001  70000           700             NaN
2020-10-22 18:20:28.401580  100000          700             5000
2020-10-22 18:30:01.281731  110000          700             200000
```

Every time I retrieve the DataFrame, I want to calculate the average traffic speed (byte/sec) for every column in the last hour. I want something like this:

```
last_hour_avgspeed(myDataFrame)

-->        
Program_A                27.7
Program_B                 0.0
Program_C               325.0
......
dtype: float64
```

There could be NaNs in the data because some columns are added within an hour. So a simple (last row - first row) / 3600 would not work.

I'm new to pandas. I first wrote a function:

```
def avgspeed(series: pd.Series):
    lo = series.first_valid_index()
    hi = series.last_valid_index()
    s = series[hi] - series[lo]
    t = (hi - lo).total_seconds()
    return s // t if t > 0 else np.nan
```

Then apply this to every column:

```
myDataFrame.last('H').apply(avgspeed)
```

I believe this do give the correct result: a pandas Series of column-speed pairs. However, I'm feeling this must not be the best way. Where is the vectorization? Can we get the result in one hit?

I have tried another method:

```
myDataFrame.last("H").resample("T").bfill().diff().mean().floordiv(60)
```

First resample the data to 1-min samples (not 1s because too slow), then calculate the mean of the differences, then divide it by 60 seconds... I think this is more silly than the first method. But the performance is actually two times faster than the first one. However, the result of columns containing NaN is somewhat different from the first one. It could because the bfill method brought some problems, I think.

So, what is the correct way to do the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand well but i think you need to use groupby and aggregate

df.groupby().agg(column='' , aggfunc=mean)

you can read more info : https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I figured out a vectorized solution:

```
def get_avgspeed(df: pd.DataFrame, offset: str) -> pd.Series:
    """Calculate average traffic speed in the final period of time based on offset."""
    
    # truncate the dataframe to the last N time units

    df = df.truncate(before=(pd.Timestamp.now()- pd.Timedelta(offset)), copy=False)
    
    # calculate the difference between the last and the first valid index per row
    t = df.index[-1] - df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
    
    # df.bfill() will back fill NaNs, so iloc[0] can give us the first valid value per row
    # then calculate the value difference: df.iloc[-1] - df.bfill().iloc[0]
    # return the speed: v = s/t
    return (df.iloc[-1] - df.bfill().iloc[0]) // t.dt.total_seconds()
    
    
avg_speed(myDataFrame, '24H')

-->
Program_A       247.0
Program_B        16.0
Program_C    197620.0
Program_X    252943.0
... ...
dtype: float64
```

In my test, the performance seems to be a little better than the no vectorized version in the question: 1.77ms vs 2.1ms.